# How to launch Electron JS build on Linux?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am trying to launch my ElectronJS app on Linux but impossible to get there.

This is my build process :

1. On Windows, I building the app for Linux with electron-packager, for amd64 arch.
2. I copy the folder generated on my Ubuntu machine and I create a .deb with electron-installer-debian package.
3. I install the application with dpkg -i my-app.deb.

In Ubuntu navigation, i found my application. But when I click on it for launch, nothing is happening...

Ideas ?